# How to retrieve only certain characters in a string?

Tags: java, indexof

I have a dialog box that asks the user to place a file name with extension into it. For example, "MyJavaProject.java". As the output I want to retrieve only what comes after the dot (or ".java" as an example). How do I do this?

Comment: yourString.split(".")[1];

Comment: Please note that you should include what you've tried. While this is simple to answer (and so you'll get lots of answers), generally S.O. frowns on not showing what work you've already done.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String input = JOptionPane.shoeMessageDialog(null,"Enter the file name");
    String[] dev = input.split(".");

    // this is to make sure you get the last string extension , if you have multiple dots just in case
    String extension = dev[dev.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final String fileExtension = ...;
final String afterPeriod = fileExtension.substring(fileExtension.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.split()` function as

```
String filename="m.txt";
String ext=filename.split(".")[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

A key point here is that when you call .split(".") on a string, you are storing the result in an array which uses the supplied string as a delimiter.

Therefore the resultant array would yield : [MyJavaProject, Java]
since arrays are indexed from zero, by accessing the first element [1] you would retrieve "Java".

Answer (score 0):

Both lastIndexOf() and split() are decent answers, but the examples provided in some of the other answers to this question won't work properly if the user enters a bad input.

For example, split()[1] won't work properly if the user enters "some.bad.input.java" where it will give you the substring "bad" rather than "java" that you might want. If you use split(), then you should get the last array element, rather than just assuming element 1.

Using lastIndexOf() will not work properly if the user inputs a string with no '.' like "somebadinput" where lastIndexOf() will return -1, and substring(lastIndexOf()+1) will just give you the entire string entered by the user.

So whichever you use, you need to validate the user input prior to trying to get the substring.